# Cannot send POST from Angular2 to Java

Tags: java, http, angular, spring-boot

I have a simple app in Angular 2. I created http.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    createPost(post: {title: string, body: string, userId: number}): Observable<any>{
        const body = JSON.stringify(post);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded');       
        return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/au', body, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Then I added in app.component.ts simple inputs with one botton:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';    
import {HttpService} from './http.service';    

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" #title>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="body">Body</label>
                <input type="text" id="body" #body>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="user-id">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="user-id" #userId>
            </div>
            <button (click)="onPost(title.value, body.value, userId.value)">Post Data</button>                
        </div>
       `,

    providers: [HttpService]

})
export class AppComponent {
    response: string;
    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService){}

    onPost(title: string, body: string, userId: string){
        this._httpService.createPost({title: title, body: body, userId: +userId})
            .subscribe(
                response => this.response = response,
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }

}
```

And in Java app create a simple method in my UserController with `@CrossOrigin` annotation and create inner class Post.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/au", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> au(@RequestBody Post post){
        System.out.println(post.getBody() + " " + post.getTitle() + " " + post.getUserId());

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    public class Post {
        private String title, body;
        private int userId;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public void setBody(String body) {
            this.body = body;
        }

        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(int userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }
    }
```

But when I start both apps and click Post botton - I have `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` and `HTTP status code 403`. What I need to do else to send POST?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? What's the problem? Do you get an `Access-Control-Allow-...` error?

Comment: I mean, I have a Java app with DB. How can I in Angular's2 home page (index.html) write login and password from DB and logged in?

Comment: Edited. I think "inject" will be correctly, not "connect"

Comment: I'd say this question is too broad.

Comment: maybe you have got a simple example or something like that? I mean, how to use Angular 2 with Java?

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Angular app and Java app are two separate applications. In a classic architecture the back-end application does not provide the front-end application.

If your question is how to provide the url of the back-end app into the front-end one, there are several strategies. One of them is to use an app bundler for example Webpack and define env variables. See this comment for more info : https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/386#issuecomment-192583352

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, thank you very much for help!